# Creating Unit tests for methods with global variables

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a program that uses a number of global variables and I was hoping to write a few unit tests for some of the methods in the program.

I was new to python when I started writing the code, and realise now that I should have been testing all along. Some of the methods in the program are as follows:

```
class Wordnet():

    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = Graph()
        self.before_at = ''
        self.after_at = ''
        self.word_part = ''
        self.gloss_part = ''
        self.lex_filenum = ''

    def process_file(self):
        self.file = open("testing_line.txt", "r")
        return self.file

    def line_for_loop(self, file):
        for line in file:
            self.split_pointer_part(line)
            self.split_word_part(line)
            self.split_gloss_part(line)
            self.process_lex_filenum(self.word_part) 

    def split_pointer_part(self, line):
        self.before_at, self.after_at = line.split('@', 1)
        return self.before_at, self.after_at    

    def split_word_part(self, line):
        self.word_part = line.split()
        return self.word_part

    def split_gloss_part(self, line):
        self.gloss_part = line.strip().split('|')
        return self.gloss_part

    def process_lex_filenum(self, word_part):
        self.lex_filenum = word_part[1]
        return self.lex_filenum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordnet = Wordnet()
    my_file = wordnet.process_file()
    wordnet.line_for_loop(my_file)
```

What is confusing me is how to variables are passing through to the test class and how I go about writing the testing methods. So far this is what I have:

```
class WordnetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.wn = wordnet.Wordnet()
        self.graph = wordnet.Graph()
        self.before_at = wordnet.before_at
        self.after_at = wordnet.after_at
        self.word_part = wordnet.word_part
        self.gloss_part = wordnet.gloss_part
        self.lex_filenum = wordnet.lex_filenum

    def test_split_pointer_part(line):
        expected = '13797906 23 n 04 flood 0 inundation 0 deluge 0 torrent 0 005',' 13796604 n 0000 + 00603894 a 0401 + 00753137 v 0302 + 01527311 v 0203 + 02361703 v 0101 | an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"'
        real = self.wn.split_pointer_part()
        self.assertEqual(real, expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
    raw_input("Press <ENTER> to exit")
```

This does not work at the moment and I know I am not doing it the right way but just can't find any specific help for this problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a runnable example to get you started:

```
import unittest
class Wordnet():

    def __init__(self):
        # self.graph = Graph()
        self.before_at = ''
        self.after_at = ''
        self.word_part = ''
        self.gloss_part = ''
        self.lex_filenum = ''

    def process_file(self):
        self.file = open("testing_line.txt", "r")
        return self.file

    def line_for_loop(self, file):
        for line in file:
            self.split_pointer_part(line)
            self.split_word_part(line)
            self.split_gloss_part(line)
            self.process_lex_filenum(self.word_part) 

    def split_pointer_part(self, line):
        self.before_at, self.after_at = line.split('@', 1)
        return self.before_at, self.after_at    

    def split_word_part(self, line):
        self.word_part = line.split()
        return self.word_part

    def split_gloss_part(self, line):
        self.gloss_part = line.strip().split('|')
        return self.gloss_part

    def process_lex_filenum(self, word_part):
        self.lex_filenum = word_part[1]
        return self.lex_filenum


class WordnetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.wn = Wordnet()

    def test_split_pointer_part(self):
        line = 'foo@bar'
        result = self.wn.split_pointer_part(line)
        answer = ('foo', 'bar')
        self.assertEqual(len(result), 2)
        for r, a in zip(result, answer):
            self.assertEqual(r, a) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can the test classes be done in a different file or is it much easier to do it this way?

Comment: The test classes should be in a different file; I put it all in one just to make the example simpler.